# Why setting PlotPoints make my 3d contour plot broken?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make a iso surface plot from some data using ContourPlot3d. My data is a 3 dimension data with form like `{{x,y,f[x,y]},...}`. I first make this data into 4d by rotating it along the x axis, so that `{x,y,f[x,y]}` becomes `{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]}`. Then interpolate them and plot the interpolated function. But sometimes I get a broken surface.

Here is the detail:

```
Get["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24667921/data.dat"];
f = Interpolation[data];
f3d[x_, y_, z_] := f[x, Sqrt[y^2 + z^2]];

ContourPlot3D[
 Abs[f3d[x, y, z]]^2, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 20, Contours -> {1*^-6}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, -1.3, 2.9}, ViewVertical -> {0.2, -1, 0.2}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

We can see two dark spot on the surface. If I remove the `PlotPoints->20`, the holes are gone. And this seems not caused by the same reason from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/my-donut-has-holes-in-it) post, because I still see the broken surface as I exported to pov file and rendered in povray.

For my problem I can't just remove the `PlotPoints->20` option, because I have to generate the same kind of plots from a serial of data. And I have to set a PlotPoints to a number to make sure the contour can be found.

[image]

Comment: In *Mathematica* 8.0.4 `InterpolatingFunction` just does not work with your `data`: calling for example `f[data[[1, {1, 2}]]]` returns whole `InterpolatingFunction` unevaluated.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm using version 9. It's quiet strange that it doesn't work in version 8.

Comment: Setting `MaxRecursion -> 1` (along with `PlotPoints -> 20`) gives me an artifact-less graphic in 32-bit 9.0.1 (on Lubuntu 14.04, fwiw). I don't have an answer to your actual question (why it otherwise breaks), though. Possibly a bug in the adaptive sampling algorithm controlled by `MaxRecursion`... maybe worth a report to WRI Support?

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but maybe it's worth reminding you that `RegionPlot3D` works much faster and also doesn't show the artifacts (using e.g., `PlotPoints->90`), as I mentioned in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75535/245).

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, try `MaxRecursion-> 0` and increase `PlotPoints`. Hope it helps.

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Abs[f3d[x, y, z]]^2, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, Contours -> {1*^-6}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, -1.3, 2.9}, ViewVertical -> {0.2, -1, 0.2}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

> [image]

Comment: @bbgodfrey At least I think it's a clue as to *why*... the recursive subdivisions seem to create an incorrect mesh.

Comment: @bb, it's a workaround, so an admissible answer in my book, even if it (was) terse.